# How can I get will_paginate to correctly display the number of entries?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, will-paginate

[WillPaginate](https://github.com/mislav/will_paginate) has a `page_entries_info` view helper to output text like "Displaying contracts 1 - 35 of 4825 in total".

However, I'm finding that when I try to use it like this...

```
= page_entries_info @contracts
```

It outputs...

> Displaying Contract 1 - 35 of 4825 in total

(It outputs the singular name of the model, rather than pluralized, all lower case.)

Do I need to feed it some other param?

I tried `page_entries_info @contracts, :model => Contract` but got the same result.

I'm using version 3.0.3 -- the current version.

Incidentally, can someone point me to the API docs for WillPaginate?

Comment: You can store the count in an instance variable before doing the pageination.

Comment: Some documentation: http://mislav.uniqpath.com/will_paginate/

Answer (score 4):

will_paginate API docs:  https://github.com/mislav/will_paginate/wiki/API-documentation

**Short answer**

You can specify the model option as a string, which will be correctly pluralized.

```
page_entries_info @contracts, :model => 'contract'
# Displaying contracts 1 - 35 of 4825 in total
```

**Longer answer**

The [will_paginate docs suggest](https://github.com/mislav/will_paginate/wiki/I18n) that you use [the i18n mechanism](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html) for customizing output.  This is kind of a pain since AFAICT you have to write out singular and plural form for all of your models in the `config/locales/*.yml` files (e.g., en.yml), and the `%{foo}`-style syntax doesn't seem to be ERB, but just placeholders, so you can't do things like `%{foo.downcase}`.

If you write your own helper, you get complete control over the output.  For example:

```
def my_page_info(collection)
  model_class = collection.first.class
  if model_class.respond_to? :model_name
    model = model_class.model_name.human.downcase
    models = model.pluralize
    if collection.total_entries == 0
      "No #{models} found."
    elsif collection.total_entries == 1
      "Found one #{model}."
    elsif collection.total_pages == 1
      "Displaying all #{collection.total_entries} #{models}"
    else
      "Displaying #{models} #{collection.offset + 1} " +
      "to #{collection.offset + collection.length} " +
      "of #{number_with_delimiter collection.total_entries} in total"
    end
  end
end

# Displaying contracts 1 - 35 of 4,825 in total
```